# Visual Studio 2019 Blazor Application System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException after copying solution to new location - still referencing old location

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, blazor, asp.net-core-3.1

After copying my solution to a new location, I received this build error

```
"System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'C:\Users\<UserName>\source\repos\<SolutionName>\<ProjectName>\Client\bin\Debug\net5.0\wwwroot\'
```

I am new to Blazor .NET Core, and if I had this kind of problem with a .NET Framework solution, executing `Build -> Clean Solution` would fix the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While looking in each project for any reference to the file path in question, I noticed that it was referencing the debug folder in bin, so I deleted the bin folders in each project (Client, Shared, and Server) as well as the obj folders in each project, just in case.  This solved the problem.  I had, at first tried to "clean" the projects with the clean command in Visual Studio 2019, but this did not work for me.

Comment: a good old 'Clean' did it for me